# php GD library Images below a certain size don't show

Tags: php, gd

I'm taking a linked image, and making my own resized versions of them using the imagecopyresampled().

When trying to show GD library resampled images, those below a certain size (around 160px width) show up only as a bunch of gibberish (ex: '����JFIF��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality ��C').

I checked the images themselves, and they were stored fine and show up correctly when opened in a picture viewer. However, printing them to browser just doesn't work. When I change the pixel size to a larger pixel size, it works fine.

I'm showing the images in the browser like this

```
$handle = fopen($fileName, "rb");
$img = fread($handle, filesize($fileName));
fclose($handle);
$imgSize = strlen($img);
$image_type = exif_imagetype($fileName);
header('Content-Type: image/JPEG');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Content-Length: $imgSize");
print $img;
return true;
```

Right now I'm starting to believe it's something to do with the GD library. Anyone else have any further insight into this?

Thanks.

EDIT:

One of Brad's suggestions showed me the right way. As usual, it was a completely boneheaded mistake. I can't answer my own question yet so I figured I'd make an edit instead.

What I forgot to include in my initial description, was that the previous code was all in one of my models, and I then called a function to show the image in my controller.

I'd recently switched to Symfony2, and have been using the Response return pretty much everywhere in my controllers. However, I'd been reusing my old show image code, which had been written without Symfony. I had a "show image" type of function, which I called in my controller and then returned an empty Response. Thus, Symfony's Response return messed up the encoding. Advanced browsers were able to auto correct for large images, but not for small ones.

My final solution became

In my model

```
$handle = fopen($fileName, "rb");
$image= fread($handle, filesize($fileName));
fclose($handle);
$image_type = exif_imagetype($fileName);
```

In my controller

```
return new Response($image, 200, array('Content-Type' => $image_type));
```

Comment: How are you outputting the images, exactly? What is the context of the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the raw image data, which means the browser is, for some reason, not registering the content type.

What I suspect is happening is that whatever browser you are testing with is case-sensitive to the `Content-Type` header **value**.

Change `image/JPEG` to `image/jpeg`, and see if that works for you.

As for an explanation of why it works with larger images...  It is likely that the `Content-Type` is never being recognized as a known type.  Browsers will look at the actual content they received, to try to figure out what type it is.  There is probably something in its content sniffing function that looks at small lengths and says, "Nope, probably not an image", and moves on.

Comment: I've tried various forms of image/jpeg and they all don't work.

Comment: I've never considered that the browser is the one doing the content recognition though. I'll have to look into that. That might indeed be the issue. Thanks

Comment: @saccharine, Then, I think you need to provide more context.  Better yet, can you post a link?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You were right. I'd switched to Symfony recently, and had been returning an empty Response, which threw off my stuff. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

they are so many ways to achieve a working script .. i give you 2 examples using  `file_get_contents` and `read_file`

**Example 1**  using `file_get_contents`

```
$fileName = "http://www.bestmastersineducation.com/teaching-to-tests/standardized-tests.jpg"; // Full path to image
$img = file_get_contents($fileName);
$imgSize = strlen($img);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header ('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
header ("Content-Length: $imgSize" );
echo $img;
return true;
```

See the DEMO : http://codepad.viper-7.com/GFqsLe

Now to Create a smaller sample of the image

```
header ( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );
header ( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );

$new_width = 100;
$new_height = 100;

$fileName = "http://www.bestmastersineducation.com/teaching-to-tests/standardized-tests.jpg"; // 
$img = file_get_contents ( $fileName );
$im = imagecreatefromstring ( $img );
if ($im !== false) {
    list ( $width, $height ) = getimagesize ( $fileName );
    $imageSample = imagecreatetruecolor ( $new_width, $new_height ); // new                                                    // Height
    imagecopyresampled ( $imageSample, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );
    imagejpeg ( $imageSample, null, 100 );
}
```

Demo Link : http://codepad.viper-7.com/gXmoDW

**Example 2** Using `readfile`

```
$fileName = "a.jpg" ;   //Full path to image
$imgSize = filesize($fileName);
$imageType = exif_imagetype($fileName);
header('Content-Type:' . image_type_to_mime_type ($imageType));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Content-Length: $imgSize");
readfile($fileName);
```

Optional

**if you want to force download use this instead**

```
$fileName = "a.jpg" ; //Full path to image 
$imgSize = filesize($fileName);
$imageType = exif_imagetype($fileName);
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($fileName));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header("Content-Length: $imgSize");
readfile($fileName);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: The output type is clearly JPEG.  You can see it in his reference to "gibberish".  While I agree that dynamically outputting the correct `Content-Type`, that isn't the problem at hand.

Comment: I never said `Content-Type` was the problem .. only present a solution definitely there is no single way to get the JOb done @Brad

Comment: Thanks Baba for the tips. Unfortunately, the issue that I had was that I'd switched to Symfony recently and used my old code, while still returning an empty Symfony Response() which affected the image encoding. I rewrote my code to output the image inside the Response variable and fixed it.

Comment: Oh .... its good to know you fixed it  .. funny enough i also added example on `imagecopyresampled` thinking that  could be the issue form the error you gave .... nice one